# how to implement search engine on existing mvc page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, search-engine

Suppose I have MVC application with some static and dynamic web pages. How to add search feature for such site?

I dont want to create simple page searching for the data contained in database, I want to be able to index whole pages as they are displayed to customer.

Any solution for ASP.NET MVC4/5?

Shell I use existing solution (which?) or create my own one ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What problem are you actually trying to solve? Building a search engine from scratch seems like it is probably not the best idea... consider simplifying your navigation if it is hard to find content on your site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build a search engine in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933464/how-to-build-a-search-engine-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: it's the product of the company I work for.

You can use [SearchUnit](https://keyoti.com/products/search/dotNetWeb/index.html) for indexing/searching MVC web sites.  There's a free Community version, and a more powerful paid version.

I don't know the specifics of what you need, but it's easier to use and more rounded (eg. includes spell checking, many document format parsers) than other options such as Lucene (IMHO, let me know if you disagree).

MVC specifics are [here](https://keyoti.com/products/search/dotNetWeb/tutorials/setup-MVC-search-engine/).